# How to prove that for every integer $k \geq 2$ we have $k^{1/k} \leq e^{1/e}$ without using the first derivative test?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

I just stumbled across this cool property, by doing some calculus I could prove it, the function $f(x) = x^{1/x}$ has a local maximum at $x = e$ and the derivative changes sign at that point, but I was wondering if there was other were to prove it without using the first derivative test ?

Comment: I think to prove it without using math it's much more interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a proof I saw a number of years ago
that $e^{1/e} > x^{1/x}$
for $x > e$.
All it uses is
$e^z > 1+z$ for $z > 0$.

If $x > e$ then
$e^{\dfrac{x-e}{e}}
\gt 1+\dfrac{x-e}{e}
= 1+\dfrac{x}{e}-1
= \dfrac{x}{e}
$
so
$e^{\dfrac{x}{e}-1}
\gt \dfrac{x}{e}
$
or
$e^{\dfrac{x}{e}}
\gt x
$
or
$e^{1/e}
\gt x^{1/x}
$.

The case $k = 2$ is
$2^{1/2} < e^{1/e}
$
or
$\ln(2) < 2/e$
and
$\ln(2) < .7$
and
$2/e > .73$.

Comment: Very nice approach!

Comment: As I wrote, I didn't discover this, but I sure remember it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $1<e^{1/e}<2$, then by induction is possible proof that:
$$(e^{1/e})^k>k$$ for all $k\geq2$

Comment: Can you elaborate at bit?  $(e^{1/e})^2 \approx 2.087 >2$  is fairly sharp, how do you conclude that from $1<e^{1/e}<2$?

Comment: $e^{1/e}$ is a constant,  is possible find the values of $e^{1/e}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ with a calculator, do you don't use a calculator?

Comment: Surely I can verily the inequality for each $k$ with a calculator. But you mentioned a proof by induction, and it would be nice to see how that works.